# ansible: how to parse output of an Oracle script (JSON_OBJECT)

Tags: ansible

There is an Oracle script that runs this query:

```
select json_object (name, value) from v$parameter where lower(name) in ...
```

output of this script:

```
{"name":"processes","value":"1000"}
{"name":"sessions","value":"1522"}
{"name":"sga_target","value":"3221225472"}
{"name":"control_file_record_keep_time","value":"7"}
{"name":"db_block_size","value":"8192"}
{"name":"compatible","value":"19.0.0.0.0"}
...
```

I register stdout_lines during sql-script execution and then parse line by line:

```
 - name: print fetched database parameters
    debug:
      msg: "{{ db_params_out.stdout_lines }}"

  - name: create list of newdb parameters from fetched result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    with_list: "{{ db_params_out.stdout_lines }}"
    when: db_params_out.stdout_lines | length > 0
```

Output looks good to me:

```
TASK [db_standby_preinstall : print fetched database parameters] *********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost -> ol79_1] => {
    "msg": [
        "",
        "{\"name\":\"processes\",\"value\":\"1000\"}",
        "{\"name\":\"sessions\",\"value\":\"1522\"}",
        "{\"name\":\"sga_target\",\"value\":\"3221225472\"}",
        "{\"name\":\"control_file_record_keep_time\",\"value\":\"7\"}",
        "{\"name\":\"db_block_size\",\"value\":\"8192\"}",
        "{\"name\":\"compatible\",\"value\":\"19.0.0.0.0\"}",
...

TASK [db_standby_preinstall : create list of newdb parameters from fetched result] ***************************************************************************
ok: [localhost -> ol79_1] => (item=) => {
    "msg": ""
}
ok: [localhost -> ol79_1] => (item={'name': 'processes', 'value': '1000'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "name": "processes",
        "value": "1000"
    }
}
ok: [localhost -> ol79_1] => (item={'name': 'sessions', 'value': '1522'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "name": "sessions",
        "value": "1522"
    }
}
ok: [localhost -> ol79_1] => (item={'name': 'sga_target', 'value': '3221225472'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "name": "sga_target",
        "value": "3221225472"
    }
}
ok: [localhost -> ol79_1] => (item={'name': 'control_file_record_keep_time', 'value': '7'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "name": "control_file_record_keep_time",
        "value": "7"
    }
}
ok: [localhost -> ol79_1] => (item={'name': 'db_block_size', 'value': '8192'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "name": "db_block_size",
        "value": "8192"
    }
}
ok: [localhost -> ol79_1] => (item={'name': 'compatible', 'value': '19.0.0.0.0'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "name": "compatible",
        "value": "19.0.0.0.0"
```

but I cannot address key/value of a fetched item, ansible fails with *The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'name' (or 'value')* if i try to use **item.name** or **item.value** instead of **item**.

P.S. I can modify Oracle script and provide output in any format. I need to parse output and assign values to corresponding variables:
newdb_processes:1000
newdb_sessions:1522
etc...

Comment: Can you show us your task in which you trying to access `item.name` (etc) and it is failing?

Comment: The same as an original task, just replaced item.to item.name
  - name: create list of newdb parameters from fetched result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.name }}"
    with_list: "{{ db_params_out.stdout_lines }}"
    when: db_params_out.stdout_lines | length > 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass each line through the `from_json` filter to get a structured object, like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    db_params_out:
      stdout_lines:
        - '{"name":"processes","value":"1000"}'
        - '{"name":"sessions","value":"1522"}'
        - '{"name":"sga_target","value":"3221225472"}'
        - '{"name":"control_file_record_keep_time","value":"7"}'
        - '{"name":"db_block_size","value":"8192"}'
        - '{"name":"compatible","value":"19.0.0.0.0"}'

  tasks:
    - name: create list of newdb parameters from fetched result
      debug:
        msg: "{{ (item|from_json).name }}"
      with_list: "{{ db_params_out.stdout_lines }}"
      when: db_params_out.stdout_lines | length > 0
```

The above playbook outputs:

```
TASK [create list of newdb parameters from fetched result] **********************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'processes', 'value': '1000'}) => {
    "msg": "processes"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'sessions', 'value': '1522'}) => {
    "msg": "sessions"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'sga_target', 'value': '3221225472'}) => {
    "msg": "sga_target"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'control_file_record_keep_time', 'value': '7'}) => {
    "msg": "control_file_record_keep_time"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'db_block_size', 'value': '8192'}) => {
    "msg": "db_block_size"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'compatible', 'value': '19.0.0.0.0'}) => {
    "msg": "compatible"
}
```

Comment: - name: create list of newdb parameters from fetched result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ (item|from_json).name }}"
    with_list: "{{ db_params_out.stdout_lines }}"
    when: db_params_out.stdout_lines | length > 0

TASK [db_standby_preinstall : create list of newdb parameters from fetched result] **************************************************
fatal: [localhost -> {{ primary_db_host }}]: FAILED! => {"msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value ({'msg': '{{ (item|from_json).name }}'}), and could not be converted to an dict.The error was: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: If you'd like to update your question to include data that reproduces those errors if I plug it into this playbook, I'd be happy to take a closer look. Otherwise, I think this solves the problem for the data you've presented in your question.

Comment: Your example works just fine and probably I know where the problem is. The first stdout_lines is empty but it still passes into the loop even if I set a condition when: db_params_out.stdout_lines | length > 0 .
I see this output for the first line of stdout_lines:
st -> ol79_1] => (item=) => {
    "msg": ""
}

Answer (score 2):

Issue is solved. The problem was in the first line of stdout_lines which is empty but still passes via filter

> when: db_params_out.stdout_lines | length > 0

I've removed this line but now I use "reject" filter in loop:

> with_list: "{{ db_params_out.stdout_lines | reject('match', '^$') }}"

And it works now, no more empty output lines.

Thanks a lot user **larsks** who pointed me to a test-case with correct data to prove that his solution works properly.